# Opcion por defecto en select con Angular 5

Tags: html, web, angular, typescript

Tengo el siguiente problema, espero que puedan ayudarme:

Tengo un formulario en mi plantilla HTML:

```
    <form #formulario="ngForm" autocomplete="off">
        <div>
            <label for="periodo">Periodo</label>
            <select id="periodo" #periodo ngModel required name="periodo">
                <option *ngFor="let periodo of periodos" [value]="periodo.id">{{periodo.fecha_inicio}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Y me gustaria saber como puedo definir una opcion por defecto en mi **select**.
Ya eh intentado agregando el atributo **[selected]="defaultValue"** pero no consiguo el resultado esperado.

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida...

**SOLUCION**

Ok, pude solucionarlo. Dejare mi respuesta por si le sirve a alguien:

Definí en mi archivo **.ts** una variable con el valor que espero establecer por defecto:

```
defaultValue = val;
```

y en mi plantilla **HTML**

```
 <form #formulario="ngForm" autocomplete="off">
        <div>
            <label for="periodo">Periodo</label>
            <select id="periodo" #periodo ngModel required name="periodo">
                <option *ngFor="let periodo of periodos" [value]="periodo.id" [selected]="default == paralelo.descripcion">{{periodo.fecha_inicio}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Tal vez te sirva esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18195305/3239070

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo creando un "index" y luego vincularlo a la opcion [selected].

También, nota el cambio que hice en el ngFor, ya que no habías cerrado las comillas.

```
<option *ngFor="let periodo of periodos; let index = index" [value]="periodo.id" [selected]="index == 1" >{{periodo.fecha_inicio}}</option>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Tambien habia explorado esta opción, sin embargo, el escenario de mi problema requería que se asigne un valor dinamico por defecto. Estoy seguro de que tu respuesta ayudara a muchos. Gracias Hugo.

Comment: La otra opción sería asignarle un  [(ngModule)]="mi_variable" al <select> (no al <option>) y luego en el onInit() asignas el valor